# Default parameters are not of the same type?

Tags: c++, parameters

I posted earlier about a problem with my constructor, I fixed it somehow. Now I am getting an error when I am trying to declare an object of type 'Rational' with userinput and another with default paramaters. When I try to use my overload operators, it gives me this error.

```
error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Rational()' and 'Rational')
  Rational xxx = test6+test5;
```

My .H files

```
#ifndef RATIONAL_H
#define RATIONAL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class Rational {
   private: 
    int num, denom;
   public:
   /* Set Numerator and Denom */
    Rational(int nu, int deno);
    int gcd(int x, int y);
    Rational operator+(const Rational& other);
    Rational operator-(const Rational& other);
    Rational operator*(const Rational& other);
    Rational operator/(const Rational& other);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& os, const Rational& rat);
    void deci();
};

#endif
```

This is my .cpp file

```
#include "Rational2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int Rational::gcd(int x, int y) {
        while (y != 0) {
             int r(x % y);   // compute remainder
         x = y;
             y = r;
        }
            return x;
}


Rational::Rational(int nu =1, int deno =1){
    if (deno == 0){
        cout << "Denominator Can't Be 0" << endl;   
    }else{
        num =  nu/gcd(nu, deno); 
        denom = deno/gcd(nu, deno);
    }
}

Rational Rational::operator+(const Rational & other){
    int nn = num*other.denom + denom*other.num;
    int dd = denom * other.denom;
    return Rational(nn, dd);

}
```

Test Main File

```
Rational test5(3,4)
Rational test6();
Rational xxx = test6+test5;
cout << xxx << endl;
```

So it should add normally, 
3/4 + 1/1, where 1/1 would be my default parameters if user does not input anything when calling an object of rational type

I am not sure if it is a problem with the default parameter from the constructor, or my operator+ method does not contain an option to add default parameters?

It should just treat the two objects of the same type

**UPDATE:**

After removing the parentheses, I get this error

```
main.cpp:32:11: error: no matching function for call to 'Rational::Rational()'
  Rational test6;
           ^
main.cpp:32:11: note: candidates are:
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
Rational2.h:13:2: note: Rational::Rational(int, int)
  Rational(int nu, int deno);
  ^
Rational2.h:13:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
Rational2.h:8:7: note: Rational::Rational(const Rational&)
 class Rational {
       ^
Rational2.h:8:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Am I suppose to create another method just declaring Rational without the parentheses in my cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the **Update:**
You've told us your default parameters are 1/1, but you have to tell the compiler, too.

You need to either put default values on your existing constructor, or provide a default constructor.

Comment: Rational::Rational(int nu =1, int deno =1){ ... } does this not declare the default parameters?

Comment: Nope. The code _calling_ the method can't see those, they're in a different translation unit. Put them in the declaration in the class definition instead.

Comment: Yeah, it looked like I had to declare a default parameter... I did it by calling another constructor method where there are no parameters, is there a way to put it within my constructor?

Comment: `Rational(int nu =1, int deno =1);` in your class declaration.

Comment: No. In your class, you have `Rational(int nu, int deno);`. That's the declaration of your constructor. Change it to `Rational(int nu=1, int deno=1);`. Then any time you call it without any parameters (or without a `deno`), the caller will use those values (or that value) instead.
(Did the comment I was replying to get deleted?)

Answer (score 3):

Your line `Rational test6();` is not defining a new variable of type `Rational`, it's defining a function called `test6` that returns `Rational`, taking in no parameters. To get the behaviour you want, remove the parentheses: `Rational test6;`

Or, if you're using C++11 I believe you can use curly braces: `Rational test6{};`

Comment: @BaoThai you haven't given `Rational` a default constructor  . either do that, or use `Rational test6(1, 1);` for example

Answer (score 1):

```
Rational test6();
```

Believe it, or not, but this gets parsed as a declaration of a function named `test6`() that returns an instance of `Rational`.

Things pretty much fall apart to pieces, from that point on.

Change this to:

```
Rational test6;
```

P.S.: you do actually have a small problem with your operator overload. It should really be:

```
Rational Rational::operator+(const Rational &other)
```